# Is there a bug in the docker containerwait api when creating a large number of containers?

Tags: docker

Is there a bug in the docker containerwait api?The logs show that it stops at the containerwait function, but I found out via docker ps -a that the container has ended and exitcode=0. With 2000+ containers created, there is a 1 in 100 chance that this will happen.When I create a smaller number of containers, this does not happen. Has anyone experienced the same problem?

Can I implement a waitcontainer api myself by polling the container state?Are there any problems with this approach?

docker version:

```
Client:
 Version:         1.13.1
 API version:     1.26
 Package version: docker-1.13.1-205.git7d71120.el7.centos.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.10.3
 Git commit:      7d71120/1.13.1
 Built:           Wed Apr 28 13:37:12 2021
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:         1.13.1
 API version:     1.26 (minimum version 1.12)
 Package version: docker-1.13.1-205.git7d71120.el7.centos.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.10.3
 Git commit:      7d71120/1.13.1
 Built:           Wed Apr 28 13:37:12 2021
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64
 Experimental:    false
```

go sdk version: v1.13.1

Comment: I've also encountered this situation: docker ps shows container status as up, but docker inspect shows container status as exited. this is strange and I can't figure out why

Comment: Is this using the Centos/Red Het version of Docker? I'm guessing it is by the 1.13.1 version. I'd suggest using the Docker .rpm from Docker itself as 1.13.1 is pretty old and I suspect it only gets security updates at this point.